# Access is denied Jenkins

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins

[Here I am trying to open my Jenkins and having this error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zOWSs.png)

Please, mention I am a junior developer and trying to learn Jenkins. I installed Jenkins on my mac with this link and install Matrix Authorization Strategy plug in. Then I changed somethings then pressed save. Boom. Access is denied. Please, help me. I tried to uninstall and install again but still the same thing. Access is denied. Please, help me with this issue. I use mac.

Comment: Login to Jenkins using the `admin` credentials. You can find the `admin` password in `/var/lib/jenkins/secrets/initialAdminPassword`

Answer (score 1):

When Matrix Authorization Strategy is enabled, you need to grant privileges to the users, too.
Login into Jenkins with an user with admin privileges, then go to the authorization configuration:

Manage Jenkins -> Configure Global Security -> Authorization

In the User/Group table, grant the necessary rights to the users.
For example: "Overall Read" for all authenticated users, etc.

If you don't have access to an admin account, edit the Jenkins server configuration file `config.xml` in the Jenkins home, setting:

```
<authorizationStrategy class="hudson.security.FullControlOnceLoggedInAuthorizationStrategy">
    <denyAnonymousReadAccess>true</denyAnonymousReadAccess>
</authorizationStrategy>
```

Then, restart, login and fix the configuration.

Comment: I have no any access to anything to do. On my main page there is message Access is denied. And if I press dashboard it is not opening anything. Just saying access is denied.

Comment: I suggest to testore the default authz plugin strategy, editing the config.xml file in the Jenkins home. I update my answer